# RecyclerView in DialogFragment not scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I have a RecyclerView in a DialogFragment.  Both the Dialog fragment and recyclerview  show though when the recyclerview fills beyond the view capacity it does not scroll.

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="FoodMenuTag"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.android.cop1803.MainActivity">

    <View
    android:id="@+id/divider3"
    android:layout_width="1184dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/MarginTop_PDF_dividers"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/MarginTop_PDF_dividers"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/kCal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

        <com.example.android.cop1803.MyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_menuview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider3"
    />
```

Here's my Dialog Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_menu, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_menuview);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if(args != null) {
        cartList = args.getParcelableArrayList("key");
    MenuDialogFragmentAdapter adapter = new 
    MenuDialogFragmentAdapter(this.getActivity(), cartList);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
   }
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // Get existing layout params for the window
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    // Assign window properties to fill the parent
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
    // Call super onResume after sizing
    super.onResume();}
```

Any help with getting this to work is much appreciated.

thanks,

Jim

Comment: `com.example.android.cop1803.MyRecyclerView` is a custom `View`?

Comment: yes it is a custom view

Comment: And did you declare like that or you are using it as standard RecyclerVew?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I was not accounting for the full height of my recycler view. So it was actually working but the height was extending it beyond the bottom boundary. Once I made a few adjustments to the height it worked.  Here's the XML that on landed on.

```
<com.example.android.cop1803.MyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_menuview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider3" />
```

I don't like the height being a fixed value so I'll likely change via code.
thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

try adding nested scrolling to the recyclerview, see if its works.

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```